# Адаптация Winforms под экран C#

Tags: c#

У меня монитор (16:9 - 1920/1080). Делал под своё разрешение. Я думал что Win Forms C# сами подстраивают разрешеник, как оказалось - нет. На монике (4:3 - 1280/1024) программа улетает за границы экрана.
Как сделать адаптацию формы под разрешение экрана?
Или как-то парсить разрешение в переменную, и через IF, настраивать в ручную

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы программа "подстраивалась" под разрешение экрана, нужно воспользоваться контейнерами разметки.

Вам можно попробовать, к примеру, System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel, в нем разместить все ваши элементы в соответствующих строках и столбцах, установив, к примеру, свойство Dock как DockStyle.Fill.

Кроме этого, нужно будет обратить внимание на размеры колонок и столбцов - какие-то можно выставить в виде процентного соотношения, какие-то - в виде статического значения.

Опять же, учтите, что пропорции широкоформатного и обычного дисплеев отличаются, и, что для 16x9 смотрелось органично, для 4x3 уже может быть не таким и удобным.

Поэтому, можно при загрузке окна немного изменять размеры того или иного столбца, в зависимости от разрешения текущего экрана.

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах, насколько мне известно, любого объекта, есть раздел Layout(с англ - расположения), в котором, в свою очередь, есть свойства Anchor , Autosize, AutosizeMode. С помощью этих свойств расположения объектов на форме будут меняться в зависимости от её размера. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]